# Pass and hold data in two activities

Tags: android

I have two activities (A and B). Activity A have a button and a textview  initially empty. When I click the button of the activity A the activity B is open and show a listview. 
The goal is: when I click an item of the listview it must appear in the textview of activity A. When I select a second item in the listview I must see two item in the textview of the activity A.

How I can realize the goal?

Comment: Post your code please and show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your Activity B with `startActivityForResult` and then return whatever was selected via `setResult`to `onActivityResult`.

Comment: My doubt is: when I start for the second time the activity B, the value write in the textview of the activity A is hold? I must show all item selected in the textview.

Comment: it is not stored automatically. Just store it yourself.